# Filter ng-repeat using object property

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an array as like as given below:

```
$scope.athletes= [
{
   name: 'name 01',
   measurements: [
   {
      type: 'date'
   }, {
      type: 'info',
      value: 23,
      rank: 1
   }]
},
{
   name: 'name 02',
   measurements: [
   {
      type: 'date'
   }, {
      type: 'info',
      value: 13,
      rank: 3
   }]
},
 {
   name: 'name 03',
   measurements: [
   {
      type: 'date'
   }, {
      type: 'info',
      value: 17,
      rank: 2
   }]
}];
```

I want to display results based on `rank` filter. I already have tried something, but that doesn't work. My code is given below:

```
<tr ng-repeat="athlete in  filteredEntries = (athletes | filter: measurements[1].rank )">

   <td> {{ athlete.name }} </td>

    <td > {{ athlete.measurements[1].value }} </td>

</tr>
```

And shown ouput :

```
    Name      ---   value
 ===========================
    name 01   ---    23
 ---------------------------
    name 02   ---    13
 ---------------------------
    name 03   ---    17
```

But I want the following output:

```
    Name      ---   value
 ===========================
    name 01   ---    23
 ---------------------------
    name 03   ---    17
 ---------------------------
    name 02   ---    13
```

Comment: You will want to use the order-by directive, probably with a custom comparator to compare the nested property: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy#using-a-custom-comparator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using orderBy, check below jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/twizzlers/7peLbu2m/1/

```
<div ng-repeat="athlete in athletes | orderBy: 'measurements[1].rank' ">
   <div> {{ athlete.name }} </div>
   <div > {{ athlete.measurements[1].value }} </div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps =)

Comment: If you downvoted my comment, at least tell me where I made any mistake... dont downvote answers blindly...